# How to determine maximum server load?

Tags: iis-7.5, xeon

How,

I've got a Windows 2008 IIS 7 server using Quad-core processor (XEON) with 8GB RAM - I'd like to check what maximum load it could withstand?

Is there any good way doing this?

From your experience - how many users could a server serve concurrently (for example a 1kb page)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three methods I'm aware of;

1. Setup scripted test clients that load you server to breaking point using realistic usage patterns, there are lots of ways of doing this from creating the test clients yourself to outsourcing it to specialist companies. PROs - you empirically know what your system can do, CONs - time consuming and/or expensive.
2. Do essentially the same as number 1 but only load your system to a particular level (i.e. 10%, 25%, 33%, 50% etc.) then extrapolate. PROs - cheaper/quicker than option 1 but still a good realistic method of finding approximate system limits, CONs - still not cheap and not 100% accurate.
3. Make it up based in a huge chain of assumptions with no real knowledge of who, what or where things are going to hit you. PROs - cheap, fast and a huge body of previous methodology usage (see most vendor sales material for examples), CONs - you've wasted that much small time invested as your 'results' are worthless.

So take your pick, only your business drivers can help you decide.